# What are the grammatical rules related to "be born" in this passive voice sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

How can I understand the use of "be born" in [the sentence](https://blog.samaltman.com/how-to-be-successful#:%7E:text=But%20I%27ve%20witnessed%20enough%20people%20be%20born%20with%20the%20deck%20stacked%20badly%20against%20them%20and%20go%20on%20to%20incredible%20success%20to%20know%20it%27s%20possible.) "But I've witnessed enough people be born with the deck stacked badly against them and go on to incredible success to know it's possible"? Should it be changed to "who were born"?

If "who were born" is used, the original sentence can be separated into these three: "I've witnessed enough people", "Those people were born with the deck stacked badly against them", and "But they went on to incredible success to know it's possible".

And I wonder if its voice has become active.

What are the differences between the passive and active voices in this case, and where is the "to be" in the original sentence? Please provide a clear explanation of the grammatical rules involved.

Comment: It's a badly written piece by an 'inspirational' 'how to be successful' type of person. Such people are not always great writers of English. I would say that 'be born' implies that he was present at each birth, which is unlikely.

Comment: yeah it's awful. The big problem is with 'witnessed'. 'Being born' is an event you can witness. 'Going onto success' isn't really an event, it's a process and it doesn't make sense to talk about 'witnessing' it in the same paragraph as you talk about someone being born. At minimum you could go with 'I've known many people who were born with the deck stacked .... who have gone on ....'

Comment: yeah it's awful. But I can't easily explain why, given I have no problem with, for example, *I've known people [[to] be] born with [two heads, or whatever].*

Comment: I've known many people born with the deck stacked against them who crashed and burned. This guy is a snake oil salesman. Maybe the bad English is a gullibility filter, like in phishing emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Be born" is passive.

The active equivalent is "bear", as in "She will bear a daughter". This is grammatical, but pretty rare in ordinary modern English (most people would say "She will have a daughter").

"Witness", like "hear" and "watch", can take either a noun phrase ("I witnessed the ceremony"), an *-ing* clause ("I witnessed them getting married"), or an infinitive clause without *to* ("I witnessed them get married").

So grammatically, "I've witnessed enough people **be born** with the deck stacked badly against them and **go on** ..." is fine. Whether it makes sense is a different matter, as the commenters have pointed out.

Your emendation "I've witnessed enough people **who were born** with the deck stacked badly against them and **who went on** ..." is also grammatical, but it has a different meaning (making arguably even less sense), because the object of "witness" in this sentence is the people not the events of their lives, but "witness" normally refers to events.

Comment: I don't understand why my emendation is more nonsensical. It can be separate into these sentences: "I've witnessed enough people", "Those people were born with the deck stacked badly against them", and "But they went on to incredible success to know it's possible".

Comment: Because "witness people" doesn't make sense. What you witness is something happening, not something that is. That is part of the meaning of "witness" as opposed to "see" or "observe".